# Error occured when assign int to char

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
char ch;

ch = 65;
System.out.println(ch);
```

It's compiled with no error and produce `A` as the output.

But when I've tried to compile this following

```
int n = 65;
char ch;
ch = n;
System.out.println(ch);
```

javac won't compile this and prompt

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
```

I think both `ch` in each code have the same value and the same type of literal.
Can you explain why do I get error when I trying to compile the second code?

Comment: What is the maximum value of a `char` and of a `int` ? Then it would seems pretty obvious ;)

Comment: @AxelH but is it "obvious" why you can assign `65`, also an int, to it? I know why, I'm challenging you to explain why you think it is obvious though.

Comment: @AndyTurner it should seems obvious because of the not specific message used. It is a _possible lossy conversion_. But I guess it is because I know too.